# Raspberry Pi NoIR Camera - PiCamera/Raspistill

Tags: python, raspicam

I have a RPi Noir V2 camera running on my Pi Zero w.

I have been taking time lapse pictures from dusk till dawn and have had different results using Python 3 PiCamera and the shell command Raspistill.

With RaspiStill I used:

```
raspistill -ss 2000000 -ISO 1200 -sh 50 -br 50 -sa -75 -o image.jpg
```

The output was as follows:

[image]

This is the result I wanted.

I used the same settings with a Python 3 script:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep

camera = PiCamera()

camera.start_preview()
camera.brightness = 50
camera.sharpness = 50
camera.saturation = -75
camera.ISO = 1200
camera.shutter_speed = 2000000
camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/image.jpg')
sleep(10)
camera.stop_preview()
```

And got the following result:

[image]

Which turned out nothing like the raspistill image.

Can anyone help or advise how I can get the Python 3 script picture to output the same as the raspistill pictures?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give 2 seconds sleep after `camera = PiCamera()` to initialize camera. You don't need to run `start_preview()` if you not need use it. If need it, start it **after** setup camera parameters.